# How to use StringBuilder properly instead of an excessively long method

Tags: java

I'm wondering how I can use the `StringBuilder` properly because my current method (http://pastebin.com/VHjM0KeQ) is way too long, I'm sure I can do a loop or a string builder I'm just not sure how to, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As everything but the case for 0 arguments and for more then 20 arguments is pretty much the same you can easily use a `StringBuilder` along with a loop to add your words to the text.

Like this:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Usage: /pm <Target> <Message>");
} else if (args.length > 20) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Error: Maximum of 20 words.");
} else {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA).append("[PM] ");
    sb.append(player.getName() + " > " + targetPlayer.getName());
    sb.append(ChatColor.WHITE);
    for (final String word : args) {
        sb.append(word).append(' ');
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length - 1);
    targetPlayer.sendMessage(sb.toString());
}
```

I used a array loop because it just works nicely here. Instead of

```
for (final String word : args) {
    sb.append(word).append(' ');
}
```

you could also write

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    sb.append(args[i]).append(' ');
}
```

You might understand the second solution a little better.

Comment: +1, that's roughly what I'd have done. A tiny enhancement would be to make the maximum a constant.

Comment: Yes, sure thing. I just did not want to introduce more changes then absolutely necessary, in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would slightly improve from using StringBuilders, that's true:

```
targetPlayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "[PM] " 
+ player.getName() + " > " + targetPlayer.getName() 
+ ChatColor.WHITE + " " + args[0])
```

should be changed to:

```
targetPlayer.sendMessage(
    new StringBuilder()
    .append(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA).append("[PM] ")
    .append(player.getName()).append(" > ")
    .append(targetPlayer.getName()).append(ChatColor.WHITE)
    .append(' ').append(args[0]).build());
```

Note: the compiler does that for you internally, so there won't be much performance gain. However your code will be easier to debug, because the compiled code will be consistent with the source code. Otherwise, when you debug, you will keep jumping inside `StringBuilder.append()` calls you don't have in your source code.

but the main problem I see with your code is that you should change your many if() clauses to a switch statement:

```
switch(args.length){
 case 0: dosomething(); break;
 case 1: doSomethingElse();break;
 default: doSomethingEntirelyDifferent();break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if(args.length == 0) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Usage: /pm <Target> <Message>");
} else if(args.length > 20 && player.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]) != null){
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Error: Maximum of 20 words.");
} else {
    StringBuilder argsConcat= new StringBuilder();
    for(int i;i<args.length;i++) {
        argsConcat.append(" "+args[i]);
    }## Heading ##
    targetPlayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "[PM] " + player.getName() + " > " +        targetPlayer.getName() + ChatColor.WHITE + argsConcat.toString());
}
```